# Updating a belongs_to model after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, after-save

I have a User model that `has_many :comments` and a Comment model that `belongs_to :user`.

I have want to gather `comment.ratings` to set `user.rating` so I have an `after_save` method in my Comment model that I call. However this never gets called.

Here is the method:

```
def update_user_rating
  user = User.find(self.is_about)
  user.trip_rating = (Comment.find_all_by_is_about(self.is_about).collect { |comment| comment.rating }.sum) / 
    Comment.find_all_by_is_about(self.is_about).count
end
```

I checked the ruby code and it works on the console, so I assume its not the ruby code.

Yes I do have after_save :update_user_rating in the model as well.

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Based on the debugger I saw that the first part of the user.trip_rating= is never executing. Meaning I tried to do `next` on that line but it never went through so I am assuming that line is the problem. However checking in rails console again, I saw that it works there. I don't understand!

**SOLVED**: Here is how I solved the problem although I don't like it. I removed the after_save callback and added a method to the user model to calculate its own ratings, and called it in the controller.

Comment: i guess you are not saving the user object. Type at the end `user.save`

Comment: I added it but still nothing has changed. it made sense though thanks.

Comment: can you try `user.save!` and if there is a problem saving it it will error it out

Comment: @Zippie wouldn't call `user.save` inside the `update_user_rating` method cause infinite recursion since that save will call another `update_user_rating`?

Comment: it's not a infinite recursion since it's a callback from `comments` not `users`

Comment: user.save! did stop the comment from saving so I am assuming there is a problem but I couldn't figure out where. I haven't checked the development.log, is it possible I can see it there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `update_user_rating` is being called, but some line in the method is failing.

Try
`user = User.find(self.user_id)` or `user = User.find_by_is_about(self.is_about)`

Comment: Probably should be `user = User.find(self.user_id)`, although i don't know what `self.is_about` means nor contains

Comment: Ahh, I missed the part where this is a callback from comments and not users

Comment: user_id is the owner of a comment whereas is_about is which user it is about